# Invert y axis in Phaser

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm building a two player board game.  I want to display the board from the current player's perspective.  So if I'm the player at the "bottom" of the board, I want to invert the y-axis and move the origin to the bottom-left corner of the canvas.  It would also be nice to have mouse clicks transformed as well.  And I only want to affect the sprite's position, not their rotation -- I always want them to be pointing up.  I'm not seeing an easy way to do this with Phaser.  Is there one?

I tried doing `world.scale.setTo(1, -1)` and then `world.y = -world.height`, but modifying `world.y` doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct phaser feature however I do recommend that you run your in-game world coordinates the same as phaser, and simply swap the display coordinates, so instead of placing your board game pieces at say

```
queen.position.set( 10, 10 );
```

it would be

```
queen.position.set( 10, worldHeight - 10 );
```

From here, build a wrapper around placement of your sprites, so it knows about mirroring:

```
placePiece( sprite, x, y, direction );
```

And in this function, check for direction to see if coordinates should be flipped or not.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar question and didn't see any satisfying answers, but looking through the source, I came up with this code that I stuck in my `create` function:

```
game.world.transformCallback = function(worldTransform) {
  worldTransform.d  = -1;
  worldTransform.ty = game.height;
};
```

I have no idea if this messes some things up, but it seems to work for my initial tests. I do see that the `x` and `y` values passed into `drawRect()` are now for the *bottom-left* of the rect, instead of the top-left. Which makes sense, but is something to be aware of. :-)

EDIT: Looks like text is also inverted. :-/